# Firefox .on('focusin') not working for image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus

I've been tinkering with jQuery events and I stumbled upon an very interesting situation (Firefox bug?) that I can't find anywhere explaned. I want to utilize the focus event for certain HTML elements but it seems that there are some limitations, such as:

- paragraphs, divs (and probably other containers) need the *contenteditable* attribute to true to make them "focusable"
- images do not work under Firefox (but they work under Chrome and Opera) even with *contenteditable="true"*. However, adding the attribute tabIndex seems to do the trick, but it's a hack and it doesn't seem like the correct solution.

So, what is the correct behaviour? Is Firefox buggy, or Chrome/Opera's behaviour is too generous, allowing the focus event for everything that is contenteditable? Also, is there some other, less-intrusive, workaround for Firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://investorplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bacon.jpg" id="img" contenteditable="true"  />

<div id="p" contenteditable="true">text test text</div>

<input id="inp" />
</body>
</html>
```

http://pastebin.com/WeJ4XS8t

Comment: Use `hover` instead of `focusin`

Comment: Hover doesn't seem to work any more than focusin (it even doesn't work under Chrome at least). Besides, I think hover is a quite different event (hovering the mouse ovre the element) than focusin ("marking" the element as the currently active one)?

Answer (score 1):

`focusin` and `focusout` are still not supported by firefox

**Bug report:** https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787

**Polyfill:** (https://gist.github.com/nuxodin/9250e56a3ce6c0446efa)

```
!function(){
    var w = window, 
        d = w.document;

    if( w.onfocusin === undefined ){
        d.addEventListener('focus'    ,addPolyfill    ,true);
        d.addEventListener('blur'     ,addPolyfill    ,true);
        d.addEventListener('focusin'  ,removePolyfill ,true);
        d.addEventListener('focusout' ,removePolyfill ,true);
    }  
    function addPolyfill(e){
        var type = e.type === 'focus' ? 'focusin' : 'focusout';
        var event = new CustomEvent(type, { bubbles:true, cancelable:false });
        event.c1Generated = true;
        e.target.dispatchEvent( event );
    }
    function removePolyfill(e){
        if(!e.c1Generated){ // focus after focusin, so chrome will the first time trigger tow times focusin
            d.removeEventListener('focus'    ,addPolyfill    ,true);
            d.removeEventListener('blur'     ,addPolyfill    ,true);
            d.removeEventListener('focusin'  ,removePolyfill ,true);
            d.removeEventListener('focusout' ,removePolyfill ,true);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            d.removeEventListener('focusin'  ,removePolyfill ,true);
            d.removeEventListener('focusout' ,removePolyfill ,true);
        });
    }

}();
```